# Stop Youtube when changing between tabs (Quicktabs)

Tags: javascript, theming, blocks

I am trying to stop a Youtube video when I change between tabs using QuickTabs but the video is still running, even in the iPad, I can even play the both videos, in this case Trailer and Full Movie at same time.

By the way, I am using the vanilla Youtube iFrame.

Comment: You should probably take a look at youtube API, this is not a Drupal related question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this post should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094397/how-can-i-stop-a-video-with-javascript-in-youtube.

As @Pan Chrono said, it's not a drupal related question, more a youtube one.

What you basically need is:

- change the way the youtube video is embed. It's actually using an iframe, you need a "embed" tag.
- add "enable_js=1" to your URL so you can use Youtube Api
- add a custom JS file to your page, and do some little jQuery code so that the video is stopped (with `var myPlayer = document.getElementById('playerid'); myPlayer.stopVideo();`) when you click on one of your tab

Comment: Thank you, I'm working on that and it's a right point to start.